# Is it possible to only highlight certain part of image (opacity)?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have applied opacity to the image. Here is the code :-

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="DelSilverlightApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Image Source="Vista.jpg"  Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Opacity="0.8"/>
        <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="254" Height="143"  Opacity="0.6" Canvas.Left="223" Canvas.Top="272" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I want that only the area of the image inside of Grid should be set to opacity of 1 else it should remain 0.8. Any ideas how can i do that? This is very vital to my application but somehow i can't find a solution to it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Image is in the Canvas not the Grid...?

Comment: @Aaron :- Yes! it is in canvas. Exactly the way you see it. If you have got any other solution in mind with any other layout changes but the same look and feel then also tell me.

Comment: You need this work in Silverlight?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones : Yes i need it in Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this in a Generic and re-usable way is to use an OpacityMask with a VisualBrush and bind the values within the VisualBrush to the Image and the Grid. This way, it will work when the Image and Grid move around and change in Size etc. The VisualBrush can contain a Canvas and a Rectangle to achieve the 0.8 and 1.0 Opacity. Opacity can't be used on the Canvas however since it will effect the Opacity of the Rectangle so Background will do instead. 0.8 is equal to #CC000000. I used #50000000 to show the effect more clearly.

[image]

**Update**
Some workarounds were needed for the Silverlight version of this so I uploaded my sample app here: http://www.mediafire.com/?8pbj5b9t72m5191

**WPF Version** (Silverlight version will also work in WPF)

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <local:SubtractMultiConverter x:Key="SubtractMultiConverter"/>
        <local:MaxValueMultiConverter x:Key="MaxValueMultiConverter"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Image Name="image" Source="C:\FG.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="200">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Canvas Background="#50000000"
                            Width="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualWidth}"
                            Height="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualHeight}">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF000000">
                            <Rectangle.Width>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MaxValueMultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="image" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Rectangle.Width>
                            <Rectangle.Height>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MaxValueMultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="image" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Rectangle.Height>
                            <Canvas.Left>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SubtractMultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="image" Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Canvas.Left>
                            <Canvas.Top>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SubtractMultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="image" Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Canvas.Top>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Canvas>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
    <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="254" Height="143" Canvas.Left="123" Canvas.Top="272" Opacity="0.6"/>
</Canvas>
```

**SubtractMultiConverter**

```
public class SubtractMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double value = (double)values[0];
        double subtractValue = (double)values[1];
        return value - subtractValue;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MaxValueMultiConverter**

```
public class MaxValueMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double desiredWidth = (double)values[0];
        double canvasValue = (double)values[1];
        double actualWidth = (double)values[2];
        return Math.Min(desiredWidth, actualWidth - canvasValue);
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**
I noticed you wanted this to work in Silverlight as well. Silverlight doesn't have MultiBinding but fortuanetely Colin E. has a [very nice solution for this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/08/silverlight-multibinding-updated-adding-support-for-elementname-and-twoway-binding/).
VisualBrush is also missing, but Chris C. has a [nice solution to that](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/silverlight-visualbrush-and-rounded-corners/). I had to make some changes to VisualImage to make this work.

The changes were in OnVisualChanged, I added an EventHandler for LayoutUpdated and changed RenderSize to ActualWidth/ActualHeight

```
private FrameworkElement visual = null;
private void OnVisualChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    //if (args.OldValue != null) ((FrameworkElement)args.OldValue).SizeChanged -= VisualImage_SizeChanged;
    if (args.NewValue != null)
    {
        visual = (FrameworkElement)args.NewValue;
        visual.SizeChanged += VisualImage_SizeChanged;
        visual.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(visual_LayoutUpdated);
        PrepareBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight);
    }
}
void visual_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrepareBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight);
}
```

**Silverlight Xaml**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:SubtractMultiConverter x:Key="SubtractMultiConverter"/>
    <local:MaxValueMultiConverter x:Key="MaxValueMultiConverter"/>

    <Canvas x:Key="testBorder"
            Background="#50000000"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualWidth}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF000000">
            <binding:BindingUtil.MultiBindings>
                <binding:MultiBindings>
                    <binding:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Width"
                                          Converter="{StaticResource MaxValueMultiConverter}">
                        <binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <binding:BindingCollection>
                                <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="image" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                            </binding:BindingCollection>
                        </binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </binding:MultiBinding>
                    <binding:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Height"
                                          Converter="{StaticResource MaxValueMultiConverter}">
                        <binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <binding:BindingCollection>
                                <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="image" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                            </binding:BindingCollection>
                        </binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </binding:MultiBinding>
                    <binding:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Canvas.Left"
                                          Converter="{StaticResource SubtractMultiConverter}">
                        <binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <binding:BindingCollection>
                                <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="image" Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                            </binding:BindingCollection>
                        </binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </binding:MultiBinding>
                    <binding:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Canvas.Top"
                                          Converter="{StaticResource SubtractMultiConverter}">
                        <binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <binding:BindingCollection>
                                <Binding ElementName="rectToGetXAndY" Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="image" Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                            </binding:BindingCollection>
                        </binding:MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </binding:MultiBinding>
                </binding:MultiBindings>
            </binding:BindingUtil.MultiBindings>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <local:VisualImage x:Name="visualImage"
                       Visual="{Binding Source={StaticResource testBorder}}"
                       ImageBrush="{Binding ElementName=brush}"/>
    <Image Name="image" Source="/GridImageOpacityMask;component/Images/FG.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="brush" />
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
    <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="254" Height="143"  Opacity="0.6" Canvas.Left="223" Canvas.Top="272"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: - Great solution. But tooo much of code. I did not know it would so hard just to achieve that simple effect. I am not that familiar with Multibindgs. I will have to dissect the code piece by piece to get better understanding. But the solution is perfectly what i wanted.

Comment: @Ankit Rathod: I agree, way to much code for this, but I can't think of an easier solution. I'll update if something comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another `Image` with an `OpacityMask` set to a `VisualBrush` that results in a clipping rectangle like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Image Source="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/hax.png" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Opacity="0.5"/>
    <Image Source="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/hax.png" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Rectangle Width="254" Height="143" Fill="Black"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
    <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="254" Height="143"  Opacity="0.6" Canvas.Left="223" Canvas.Top="272" />
</Canvas>
```

and here's another method using `Image.Clip`:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Image Source="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/hax.png" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Opacity="0.5"/>
    <Image Source="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/hax.png" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200">
        <Image.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="23,72,254,143"/>
        </Image.Clip>
    </Image>
    <Grid x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="254" Height="143"  Opacity="0.6" Canvas.Left="223" Canvas.Top="272" />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lateral solution:-

```
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid x:Name="ImageContainer" Height="300" Width="310" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200">
            <Image Source="Vista.jpg" />
            <Border x:Name="rectToGetXAndY" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="23, 72, 85, 33" BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF" />
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
```

This provides the same visual appearance of a vibrant rectangle in a washed out image.  The apparent rectangle can be manipulated by modifying the `BorderThickness` property.  Events from this rectangle can be trapped on the `Border` because a Transparent background has been added so it can be dragged about for example.  Other content could be added to internals of the `Border`, for example a Grid of transparent rectangles could provide some sizing features.

The accepted answer here is significantly more complex by comparison albeit a more direct answer to your actual question.