# Is there any way to colorize only part of image on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I would love to code simple image painting in HTML, CSS and probably jQuery also.

Let's say I have a original image, and I want make it colorized but only in part of hover (or 10x10px square or circle of image where cursor is).

I applied some filters to make it grayscale with CSS, but I have no idea how to colorize only hover part (not whole picture).

Example image of best result (keeping colorized advice would be great, but not necessarily).

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you have tried keep it simple to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Stackexchange isn't really the best place to brainstorm ideas like this. It's more for troubleshooting what you've already attempted. Some issues I can identify for you: targeting where the cursor is, (`.mousemove()`) creating a mask for the colorized photo (`background-clip`), etc.

Comment: You could possibly use this - but alter it to fit your needs http://jsfiddle.net/4WP2C/19/

Answer (score 6):

You could do this using `svg`'s `mask` and `filter`.

<kbd>**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/WbRdGQ?editors=101)**</kbd>

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');
img.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('c').setAttribute('cx', e.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left);
  document.getElementById('c').setAttribute('cy', e.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top);
})
```

```html
<svg id="img" width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="m" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300">
      <circle id="c" cx="-40" cy="-40" r="40" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(#f)" width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300" />
  <image mask="url(#m)" width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300" />
</svg>
```

---

You could also get a smooth transition on the circle edges by using `radialGradient`.

<kbd>**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/LExegq)**</kbd>

[image]

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');
img.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var y = e.clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  document.getElementById('r').setAttribute('fx', x);
  document.getElementById('r').setAttribute('fy', y);
  document.getElementById('r').setAttribute('cx', x);
  document.getElementById('r').setAttribute('cy', y);
});
```

```html
<svg id="img" width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="r" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="300" cy="150" r="400" fx="300" fy="150">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="12%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
    </radialGradient>
    <filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="m" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300">
      <path d="M0,0 h600 v300 h-600z" fill="url(#r)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(#f)" width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300" />
  <image mask="url(#m)" width="600" height="300" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap you image in a  [HTML  Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) and add a div element element with box-shadow

```js
$("figure").on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.shadow').css({
       left: e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - 40,
       top: e.pageY - $(this).offset().top -40
    });
});
```

```css
figure{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    overflow: hidden
}
figure:hover .shadow{
    opacity: 1
}
img{
    width: 100%
}

.shadow{
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60em rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
    <img src=http://i.imgur.com/orn8Dgf.jpg />
    <div  class=shadow></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: To those down voting this please comment it will help me thank you.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I think the reason is it doesn't work right when it is Full Page.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thank you for the input i will fix it.

Comment: It's a fine solution, but not exactly what was being asked. OP wants a desaturated image, not just darkened.

Comment: @fontophilic From what I read, the OP wants a gray image which should be colorized on hover. I upvoted this answer because it's not using `svg` so it provides additional way to do this. P.S as I upvoted the `svg` answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest avoiding CSS filters, as it is not supported in IE at all, and doesn't look like it is in the pipeline either.

I also would prefer to greyscale my images in photoshop, to have more control over the color balance and contrast. (But I'm a designer as well).

Instead, I'm going to layer a full color image over a grayscale image, fix the position of the colorful background image, and move the position of the top div with jQuery:

## HTML

```
<div class="greykitty">
  <div class="colorfulkitty" style="top: 150px; left: 280px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

## SCSS with normalize.css

```
body{
  background-color:whitesmoke;
}

div{
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.greykitty{
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/g/600/400/cats/10/");
}

.colorfulkitty{
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/10/");
  $circlesize: 150px;
  height:  $circlesize;
  width:  $circlesize;
  border-radius:   $circlesize;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;

}
```

## JS with jQuery

```
$('.greykitty').mousemove(function (colorize) {
    var X = colorize.clientX;
    var Y = colorize.clientY;
    $('.colorfulkitty').css("top", (Y - 75) + 'px');
    $('.colorfulkitty').css("left", (X - 75) + 'px');
});
```

And my codepen: http://codepen.io/fontophilic/pen/XJpVje/

Answer (score 1):

Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119327/css-or-javascript-to-highlight-certain-area-of-image-opacity), i have solution for your problem:

- Use mark to overlay image

  ```
  <div class="container">`
      <div class="bg-image"></div>
      <div class="highlight-region"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Grayscale on mark instead of image's container

  ```
   .container .bg-image { 
         opacity:0.3;
      -moz-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
           -o-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
           -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
           filter: gray;
           filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
      height:455px;
      width:606px;
  }
  ```
- set opacity = 0 on highlight-region

  ```
  .container div.highlight-region {
      height:150px; 
      width:150px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity:0;
  }
  ```

Demo can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/MT4T7/438/

Comment: It looks like bug come from backgroundPositionX not supported on firefox, i fixed it, view at http://jsfiddle.net/MT4T7/438/.

Comment: This is the solution I prefer, thanks for sharing !