# How to remove or hide opacity from the image in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image which is showed as a background image. I want to set default opacity to 0.5. And wanted some part to be shown without opacity in image. Will it possible purely in css, html, javascript/jQuery?

Below is the sample image.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS or JavaScript to highlight certain area of image opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119327/css-or-javascript-to-highlight-certain-area-of-image-opacity)

Comment: @azhar I'm added ananswer if it's helpful don't forget to tick it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the trick.

1. Create an overlay with `:before` or `:after` pseudo element.
2. Apply css3 transformation.
3. Use large `box-shadow` and add `overflow: hidden` on parent to hide undesired part.

```css
.image-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-holder:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 20px;
  content: '';
  right: 100px;
  top: 20px;
}

.image-holder img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by position an `<div>` over the image using **position:absolute**.I'm added an snippet below.

```css
img{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  }
#highlight{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#fff;
  opacity:0.5;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaQWH.jpg">
<div id="highlight"></div>
```